# Returning garbage data from a classes private array

Tags: c++, class

I have a class assignment where I have to write a program that will take a number from the user that is no more than 50 digits long. I have a class called `Number` that has an array called `Value[50]` used for holding the value of the number. The number length, as well as the use of arrays, is a requirement of the assignment.

The declaration of the `Number` class is as follows:

```
class Number
{
private:
    int Value[50];
    int NumberSize;
public:
    Number();
    Number(int&, int&);
    int GetValue();
    Number& operator=(const Number&);
};
```

and the definition is

```
Number :: Number(int& NumberValue, int& NewNumberSize)
{
    NumberSize = NewNumberSize;
    for (int count = NewNumberSize; count > 0; count --)
    {
        Value[NewNumberSize] = NumberValue % 10;
        NumberValue = NumberValue / 10;
        cout << Value[NumberSize] << endl;
    }
}

int Number :: GetValue()
{
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < NumberSize; count2 ++)
    {
        cout << Value[count2] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've omitted superfluous information such as `#include` directives. My problem is with the function `Number :: GetValue()`, which is written in it's current form for testing purposes. When I run the program

```
int main()
{
    Number blah = Number(12345, 5);
}
```

(again, a suitable simplification of the real thing), I get the following output

```
5
4
3
2
1
2347696
2342900
2347268
2352860
-1082078616
```

The numbers `5` to `1` at the start are expected from the `cout` found at the and of the `Number :: Number(int& NumberValue, int& NewNumberSize)` constructor, and the latter half is coming from the the `cout` in `Number :: GetValue()`, although the values are unexpected. I was expecting the same values as from the first output stream, only in reverse. The explicit values are not reproducible, although the format is (four seven digit positive integers and a ten digit negative integer). Please note, the `cout` statements in the class functions are only there for testing purposes ;)

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: The code for your assignment operator might be important in diagnosing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually setting your values.

```
Value[NewNumberSize] = NumberValue % 10
```

That just sets the same element (the last element) to the new value, and uses that same value to `cout` the result as it's calculating it. `count` isn't used inside the loop. Additionally, You probably want to set values `Value[NewNumberSize-1]` to `Value[0]`, not `Value[NewNumberSize]` to `Value[1]`. (The constructor loop will break before count reaches zero)

Passing simple values by reference when not modifying them is not good practice.

Also, `GetValue()` does not reach element zero, although that isn't contributing to incorrect output yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Value[NewNumberSize] = NumberValue % 10;
```

This should be

```
Value[count] = NumberValue % 10;
```

Also, you need to fix the range of `count` so that the array index starts from 0 to size-1, rather than 1 to size.

Finally, you are changing the value of NumberValue in the constructor, while the variable is passed by the reference. It's not a good practice. Do not your call-by-reference here or do not change the value of NumberValue.